# Difficulty running a basic Elasticsearch query against dataset

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to run a boolean query against an elastic-search cluster with a basic shakespeare dataset. I've crosschecked many resources and everything seems correct, but when i run it, the speech_number scores OR operation doesn't work as expected.

I've looked through various tutorials and documentation on elasticsearch boolean queries and I still haven't found out why the logic doesnt work as expected.

```
"query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "match": {"play_name": "Henry IV"}
                    },
                    {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [
                                {"range": {"speech_number": {"lte": 50}}},
                                {"range": {"speech_number": {"gte": 4}}}
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

A sample of the shakespear.json file which im running the queries against is as follows:

```
{"line_id":1658,"play_name":"Henry IV","speech_number":26,"line_number":"3.1.108","speaker":"MORTIMER","text_entry":"Yea, but"}
{"index":{"_index":"shakespeare","_type":"line","_id":1658}}
{"line_id":1659,"play_name":"Henry IV","speech_number":26,"line_number":"3.1.109","speaker":"MORTIMER","text_entry":"Mark how he bears his course, and runs me up"}
{"index":{"_index":"shakespeare","_type":"line","_id":1659}}
{"line_id":1660,"play_name":"Henry IV","speech_number":26,"line_number":"3.1.110","speaker":"MORTIMER","text_entry":"With like advantage on the other side;"}
{"index":{"_index":"shakespeare","_type":"line","_id":1660}}
{"line_id":1661,"play_name":"Henry IV","speech_number":26,"line_number":"3.1.111","speaker":"MORTIMER","text_entry":"Gelding the opposed continent as much"}
{"index":{"_index":"shakespeare","_type":"line","_id":1661}}
{"line_id":1662,"play_name":"Henry IV","speech_number":26,"line_number":"3.1.112","speaker":"MORTIMER","text_entry":"As on the other side it takes from you."}
{"index":{"_index":"shakespeare","_type":"line","_id":1662}}
{"line_id":1663,"play_name":"Henry IV","speech_number":27,"line_number":"3.1.113","speaker":"EARL OF WORCESTER","text_entry":"Yea, but a little charge will trench him here"}
{"index":{"_index":"shakespeare","_type":"line","_id":1663}}
{"line_id":1664,"play_name":"Henry IV","speech_number":27,"line_number":"3.1.114","speaker":"EARL OF WORCESTER","text_entry":"And on this north side win this cape of land;"}
{"index":{"_index":"shakespeare","_type":"line","_id":1664}}
{"line_id":1665,"play_name":"Henry IV","speech_number":27,"line_number":"3.1.115","speaker":"EARL OF WORCESTER","text_entry":"And then he runs straight and even."}
{"index":{"_index":"shakespeare","_type":"line","_id":1665}}
{"line_id":1666,"play_name":"Henry IV","speech_number":28,"line_number":"3.1.116","speaker":"HOTSPUR","text_entry":"Ill have it so: a little charge will do it."}
{"index":{"_index":"shakespeare","_type":"line","_id":1666}}
{"line_id":1667,"play_name":"Henry IV","speech_number":29,"line_number":"3.1.117","speaker":"GLENDOWER","text_entry":"Ill not have it alterd."}
{"index":{"_index":"shakespeare","_type":"line","_id":1667}}
{"line_id":1668,"play_name":"Henry IV","speech_number":30,"line_number":"3.1.118","speaker":"HOTSPUR","text_entry":"Will not you?"}
{"index":{"_index":"shakespeare","_type":"line","_id":1668}}
{"line_id":1669,"play_name":"Henry IV","speech_number":31,"line_number":"3.1.119","speaker":"GLENDOWER","text_entry":"No, nor you shall not."}
{"index":{"_index":"shakespeare","_type":"line","_id":1669}}
{"line_id":1670,"play_name":"Henry IV","speech_number":32,"line_number":"3.1.120","speaker":"HOTSPUR","text_entry":"Who shall say me nay?"}
{"index":{"_index":"shakespeare","_type":"line","_id":1670}}
{"line_id":1671,"play_name":"Henry IV","speech_number":33,"line_number":"3.1.121","speaker":"GLENDOWER","text_entry":"Why, that will I."}
```

The expected result should be: play_name AND (speech_number <= 50 OR speech_number >=4)
What i get is: play_name AND (speech_number <=50 AND speech_number >= 4)

Comment: have you tried filtered nested boolean query?

Comment: yes, i tried using filter but no luck

Comment: @DejanMarić, I tried using a filtered query again but i tried it with "constant_score" and it works. I didnt use constant_score before. Furthermore, I'm actually a beginner to the world of ES, and so is it possible if you could explain to me why it would work with filter and not the approach i used before? Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the query is doing:

- Must match: 
  1) Any of the words from "Henry IV" [1 see below]
  2) A `speech_number` <= 50  [OR] `speech_number` >=4

What Elasticsearch is also doing, is assigning a score: So everything inside the `must` should match and then everything inside `should` queries is boosting results (at least one of a `should` has to match)

To boost a higher `speech_number` more (**don't do this**) you could have more matching `should` statements:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": { 
                        "play_name": "Henry IV"
                    }
                },

                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "range": {
                                    "speech_number": { "lte": 50 }
                                }
                            },

                            {
                                "range": {
                                    "speech_number": { "lte": 40 }
                                }
                            },

                            {
                                "range": {
                                    "speech_number": { "lte": 30 }
                                }
                            },

                            ...
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

So a part of the problem could be `lte: 50` will allow <4, and `gte:4` >50. But I don't see any outsiders in your results. If it's the ordering. The `range` also allows for a boost (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html), so instead of having to write multiple ranges you could have:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": { 
                        "play_name": "Henry IV",
                        "operator": "and
                    }
                },

                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "range": {
                                    "speech_number": { 
                                        "gte": 25,
                                        "lte": 50,

                                        "boost": 3
                                    }
                                }
                            },

                            {
                                "range": {
                                    "speech_number": { 
                                        "gte": 4,
                                        "lte": 50
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

[1*] match defaults to OR: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html if your data is structured, a Term or adding the operator `and` to it is more what you want. Not the problem of your question :)